# Where can I find a Python module for Stock volatility estimators using Yang Zhang method?

Tags: volatility, equities, programming

Does anyone know of a Python library that includes the calculation of historical stock volatility using the Yang Zhang estimator? I have tried and failed to find one but would expect this to have been implemented in one of the Python libraries used by quants.

Comment: R code is here: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR/blob/f680055d6448f14c8138d14ccff5bfac61382e79/R/volatility.R#L214 I would opt to implement it myself and be done with it.

Comment: An example of its use is discussed here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27741/understanding-yang-zhang-volatility-estimator

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?  I don't know of a module but I do have a python function for this

Comment: @amdopt  - I found a Udemy course with a code block for the Y-Z estimator so I've used that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's a github repository for this: "A complete set of volatility estimators based on Euan Sinclair's Volatility Trading."

https://github.com/jasonstrimpel/volatility-trading